# Summing up values in one column in specific way

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a a simple table:

```
id     amount
 1.      40
 2.      50
 3.      60
```

I would like to create a query that will return an id number with the sum in a way that first id will have sum 40 , second id will have 40+50=90 , third 40+50+60= 150. Visualized output would be something like this:

```
id    sum
1.     40
2.     90
3.    150
```

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: forgot to write this information, version 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MySQL 8+ option:

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY id) sum
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

This is probably the most performant way to write your query.  If you happen to be using an earlier version of MySQL, then use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.amount) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.id <= t1.id) AS sum
FROM yourTable t1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a correlated subquery :

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t1.amount) from table t1 where t1.id <= t.id) as sum
from table t;
```

If you are working with latest version then you can do :

```
select t.*,
       sum(amount) over (order by id)
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to do...

```
SELECT id, SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY id) sum FROM TableName
```

Comment: No its not copy paste,actually i dont saw any answers when i was reply